# Reading from csv file give NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, csv, numberformatexception

I am reading datas from a csv file and set all datas into an object.At a particular point i am getting a numberformat exception (only after reading some datas)because some  datas are not numbers(That is an error inside file some charecter datas in place of numerical datas,not able to use string concept because of some integration issues with main program).At that point i need to skip that line and need to move to the nextline.Can anyone please help.Any help will be highly appreciable.

```
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(parentPath+File.separator+file),',','"');
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null &&nextLine.length!=0 ) {
    encap.setPrice((nextLine[5]));
    String mrp=encap.getPrice().split("[,]")[0];
    try {
        encap.setProduct_price(Double.parseDouble(mrp));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note:I need to skip and read next line onwards when ever numberformat exception occurs for a particular line.(value is getting correctly but my program stops whenever a numberformat exception occurs.......

encap is the object of my class....

Comment: Add stacktrace please.

Comment: What CVSReader API do you use? Why don't you utilize the CSVReaders capabilities, but read lines and split them manually?

Answer (score 0):

Expand the scope of your try catch. Brute force, put try just below while and include ALL code in that while block inside that try block.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `try..catch` is already in the right place. Just make a new `encap` for each record and it should behave as you want:

```
List<Encap> encaps = new ArrayList<Encap>(); // <- create list of results

reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(parentPath+File.separator+file),',','"');
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null &&nextLine.length!=0 ) {

    Encap encap = new Encap(); // <- create a new instance for this line

    encap.setPrice(nextLine[5]);
    String mrp=encap.getPrice().split("[,]")[0];
    try {
        encap.setProduct_price(Double.parseDouble(mrp));

        encaps.add(encap); // <- add this result to the list only if parsed ok

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```